# Nginx/Wordpress Rewrite Config

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to make a rewrite rule for my Nginx /wordpress setup since I use a translation module which makes translating via sub-directories and all registrations going to break since the registration call is posting to e.g. /de/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php instead of /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php , result 404 not found / error.

my actual Nginx config looks like this (only locations parts):

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
location /functions {
     try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }
location /payments {
     try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }
location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

I need to rewrite /de/ , /it/ , /es/ , /fi/

Comment: What plugin / module are you using ? WPML ?

Comment: I'm using gtranslate pro module

Comment: Can you specify what URIs should be altered and what should not? Everything started with `/wp-admin/`? Maybe `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` only?

Comment: everything /de/xxxxxx should be rewritten to /xxxxxx , does not matter if it will be /de/wp-admin/ or /de/wp-includes/ etc....